# Sharepoint: How to handcode a content type?

Tags: sharepoint

How can I hand code a custom content type, and with all its fields.

If you know of a step by step guide.

My whole plan to extract a content type, and reuse it , has gone sour (no surprise there, after all we are dealing with MOSS).

I guess I would like to know how to do it completely by hand, so that NOTHING can go wrong.

Thanks ( please help before I get even more furious with sharepoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if I haven't already mentioned this before, but have you read the various "Getting started with SharePoint" questions on the site? These will give you good pointers and hopefully ease your frustrations:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110341/getting-started-developing-for-sharepoint
- [SharePoint for a C# ASP.NET Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535255/sharepoint-for-a-c-asp-net-developer)
- [Learning Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953437/learning-sharepoint)
- [How to start learning SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141687/how-to-start-learning-sharepoint)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119968/good-book-for-learning-sharepoint-development
- [What is good for SharePoint beginner user tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471351/what-is-good-for-sharepoint-beginner-user-tutorials)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182449/how-to-begin-as-a-net-and-sharepoint-developer

In particular a good book like [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201) will help you a lot. It's clear and takes you through the basics very well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will have a look at this book.